# How does OpenGL handle multiple clear masks?

Tags: opengl

I've been working with OpenGL for some time now, and while I understand how to use it I'm quite interested in how it handles and understand multiple masks. Example:

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); 
//How does it understand that I want to clear the
//color buffer and the depth buffer?
```

At first I thought they might be using static variables like so:

```
GL_COLOR_AND_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT = GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT;
```

But then I realized that they would need hundreds of these to have every single possible combination, which seems silly. So how do they interpret the result and find out what two masks I wish to clear?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question; it's a simple bit test.

Answer (score 0):

As [Colonel Thirty Two](https://stackoverflow.com/users/646619/colonel-thirty-two) pointed out, [a GL implementation can use bit tests](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/mesa/mesa/tree/src/mesa/main/clear.c#n143):

```
void GLAPIENTRY
_mesa_Clear( GLbitfield mask )
{
   ...

   /* Accumulation buffers were removed in core contexts, and they never
    * existed in OpenGL ES.
    */
   if ((mask & GL_ACCUM_BUFFER_BIT) != 0
       && (ctx->API == API_OPENGL_CORE || _mesa_is_gles(ctx))) {
      _mesa_error( ctx, GL_INVALID_VALUE, "glClear(GL_ACCUM_BUFFER_BIT)");
      return;
   }

   ...

   if (ctx->RenderMode == GL_RENDER) {
      ...

      if ((mask & GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
          && ctx->DrawBuffer->Visual.haveDepthBuffer) {
         bufferMask |= BUFFER_BIT_DEPTH;
      }

      if ((mask & GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT)
          && ctx->DrawBuffer->Visual.haveStencilBuffer) {
         bufferMask |= BUFFER_BIT_STENCIL;
      }

      if ((mask & GL_ACCUM_BUFFER_BIT)
          && ctx->DrawBuffer->Visual.haveAccumBuffer) {
         bufferMask |= BUFFER_BIT_ACCUM;
      }

      assert(ctx->Driver.Clear);
      ctx->Driver.Clear(ctx, bufferMask);
   }
}
```

See the `mask & GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT`-type tests.

```
#define GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT   0x00000100 // == 0b000000100000000
#define GL_ACCUM_BUFFER_BIT   0x00000200 // == 0b000001000000000
#define GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT 0x00000400 // == 0b000010000000000
#define GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT   0x00004000 // == 0b100000000000000
```

Comment: Certainly obvious to you, but considering the level of the question, it might be worth mentioning that this works because the `*_BUFFER_BIT` values are all defined as powers of 2.